# Four Witnesses for Zina

Tags: salat, zina

Assalamu alaikum

If a Muslim say that , it is not possible to bring four witness for Zina in this modern times as defined in Quran Surah Noor verse 13, this quranic requirement doesn’t have a ground and can’t be applied today. Does this mean that he denies / rejects the verse of Quran and its teaching ?

Can we categorize this person as rejecting a part of Quran that is revealed to Prophet Muhammad and say it as an act of kuffar?

Can I pray behind this person who say this Quran verses (24:13) is not possible for this time ?

Comment: These basically are two distinct questions and should be asked separately. See [ask] and read in [our Meta](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2965/13438) how to handle this best.

Comment: It is a nonsensical opinion. Wouldn't it be much easier in the modern day to bring four witnesses due to the internet and cameras?

Answer (score -1):

Islam is mercy religion so make hard conition for 
Apply alhudood  .Especially the issues of morality so make his four witnesses not enough to saw one ..you shuld ask him that Does he deny this verse or he sees can not be applied in our time the current only from his view ? If he doesnt deny it so you can pray behind him :)